# How to get all likes of posts without using InstagramAPI?

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

I need the user id that made this likes.
It is possible?
Thank you

Comment: you want to get the user id's of likes on a post, without using Instagrams API?

Comment: @Hiscotty, hi! Yes, right

Comment: if you know username it's possible. Go to -  instagram.com/username/ and see the page code. "window._sharedData" contains JSON where you can find user id.